# Ubuntu Email without hardisk space

Tags: software-installation

HI I had recently installed Ubuntu 14.4. I would like to know what email app I could used ? I do not have much space on my hard disck and not want to use network drive. I am looking for an app which can connect to multiple email accounts and type and any updates done on the server directly (no file on hard disk).

Answer (score 0):

In the graphical environment, `Mozilla Thunderbird` is a good choice.

If you like or want to get into console (text based) apps, then `mutt` is for you.

*Most important:*  In either case, to accomplish your low disk space requirement, you will configure your email application's email server connections to use the `IMAP` protocol.  This protocol is common and easy to configure.  Most email providers and email client developers have instructions on their websites.  *Don't* use `POP` protocol which usually results in a higher disk usage on the client system.